# How to stop image shrinking when page is resized horizontally in CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I have a 1920x100 image which is inserted at the top of my page:

```
<img src="./Resources/Images/banner.jpeg" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:100px; width:100%;" name="top">
```

I'd like to have it so that when the page is resized horizontally, the image doesn't shrink with the page, but instead remains in the center of the screen, like this:

[image]

It seems like a simple thing that could be easily achieved, but I haven't found a solution.

I could put the image inside a div and set the left position of the div to be -(1920-pageWidth) / 2, but this would rely on JavaScript. I'm looking for a cleaner solution (if there is one), just to minimize complexity on the page, and maximize browser compatibility.

Is there any CSS property I could use to achieve this, or am I going the completely wrong way of achieving this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With CSS

```
div {
  background: url(./Resources/Images/banner.jpeg) no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add this css property to your image : `min-width: 1280px`

Comment: That would allow the image to shrink down to 1280px, but I believe he wants the image to stay 1920px, but stay centered on the page with the overflow hidden off of the edges of the page.

Comment: this helped me, i had the width/height set but the image was still re-sizing, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use the image as a `background-image` and use the `background-position` `center 0` value to place it in the center top of the element.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avwMT/).

Comment: This is great too. ^^

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this. (use half the image width for the `margin-left`)

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
  <img src='./Resources/Images/banner.jpeg' id='banner'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
#banner{position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;margin-left:-960px;}
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it using a div (change the width of `#wrapper`):
http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/mDkrE/

Comment: Another option is using the image as a background, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `img` element use the same image as background-image, and position in to center. It will always be centered, but may be clipped when the element is smaller then the image. You should also set background-repeat to no-repeat in case the element gets bigger.

```
div { 
  background: url(/to/img) no-repeat 50% 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```